# What would be a good application on macOS to record calls and meetings in Skype, Hangouts, etc?

Tags: macos, applications, skype, google-hangouts

I want to be able to record all kinds of calls and video conferences, such as those done in Hangouts, Skype and more.

Comment: If you're running Mojave, the built-in Screenshot tool includes video recording. Have you tried using that?

Comment: Can I suggest you read [How should I ask about getting a software recommendation?](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2180/168832) just in case it prompts you to think of further details you should add to your post?

Comment: I believe all those applications have built-in recording options, is that not an option? 

As mentioned by @JesseP. you could record your screen using your Mac but you would have to record the audio using your computer's microphone to record the sound coming from your speakers.

Comment: @JesseP. It seems fine for video, but audio is missing

Comment: @StefanPapp I havent tried it out myself yet but the iOS equivalent records sound too but has to be toggled otherwise it will only be video. It's likely there's the same sort of toggle on the macOS version.